# How to force gedit to run each window in a separate process?

Tags: ubuntu, process, gnome, window, gedit

With Ubuntu and Gnome classic desktop, sometimes I have separate windows of `gedit` open on different workspaces.

Since the program has its flaws and can be easily choked, for example by trying to undo a large replace action, I sometimes need to force-quit.

Then, all other windows are also killed. Plus, when one window is stuck, all the others are also not responding either, so I cannot continue to work on other tasks while the one that has a problem is recovering.

I guess if each window would run in a separate process, this would not happen.

Is there a way to make this happen?

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for this option:

```
-s, --standalone
      Run gedit in standalone mode.
```

(From [`man gedit`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/gedit.1.html).)

Comment: Ok cool, I tested it and it seems to be two separate processes. Any way to put this into the configuration so that by default each new window is standalone?

Comment: I'm using double click to open files and I prefer to keep the behaviour of how it groups files into windows. I usually get new windows by explicitely moving them into a new window or by being on another workspace.

Comment: @RadioControlled there doesn't seem to be dconf key for this (nothing relevant in `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.gedit`, anyway). You could: make a copy of `/usr/share/applications/gedit.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applications/gedit.desktop`, and edit the `Exec` line in the copy to use this option.

Answer (score 0):

**Question**: "How to default each new gedit window to standalone?"
Radio Controlled 17 Sept 2019

Background: gedit opens text files. The default application for opening files
of type TEXT was likely set to gedit. Application gedit opens new files in a
separate tab, not in a separate window.

**Solution**: Change the default application from gedit to another application.
Let's name the replacement application **geditx**. Application geditx will be
application gedit with a different command line option (see below).

**Implementation**:

In desktop environment MATE, a change of application for a file type is made
by right-click on a file name of that exact type, then select "Open With" and "Other Application ...".

Other desktop environments have similar steps. Ubuntu:

```
https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/files-open.html.en
```

**Wait**! To change existing gedit to geditx **requires application geditx to exist**.

**How to define geditx**? Some solutions:

1. In a terminal **create an alias**: alias geditx="gedit -s"
   While command geditx works in a terminal, it is not an option in
   the desktop environment. **Fail**.

   **However**, the alias geditx for application gedit may be useful
   in a terminal window. In the work space used by the terminal
   window, geditx would open a standalone gedit window.
2. Create a **shell script named geditx**. Application geditx will be
   an option in the desktop environment. Switching from gedit to geditx
   as the default application for files of type TEXT will change from
   opening files in tabs to opening files in separate windows.

   Warning: Opening a file within geditx (which is gedit) from the File Menu
   will open a new tab, not a new window.

   Warning: Double-click on a text file in the graphical interface will use
   gedit, unless the default application for text files is changed to geditx.

**Contents of shell script geditx**:

```
#!/bin/sh
gedit -s "$@"
```

**Details about the save location for geditx and permissions**

Save the shell script in some $HOME folder.
Make geditx executable, which translates to:

```
   Open a terminal in the folder where geditx was saved. 
   Then: chmod +x geditx
```

The folder in $HOME where geditx was saved has to be
in environment variable PATH. If not, then solve this
issue separately.

An alternative is to copy file geditx to /usr/local/bin
and execute chmod +x in that folder. This requires
administrator access to the folder /usr/local/bin which
is normally done in Linux as follows:

```
sudo cp geditx /usr/local/bin
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/geditx
```